# 3D C# XNA Model not drawing until rotated (and transparency issue)

Tags: c#, model, xna, transparency, draw

**Problem 1: Model not drawing until rotated:**
So this is probably something really simple I can't figure out.. 
My model draws fine, but only after I rotate it. It's not drawn otherwise.
Here are some extracts of my code:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    Model spaceShip;
    Matrix world;         //object world transformation
    SpaceShip player;

    Matrix view, proj;

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 30000, 0), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Forward);
        proj = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView((float)Math.PI / 4.0f, (float)graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / (float)graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, 0.1f, 100000);
        //world = Matrix.CreateTranslation(Vector3.Zero);    //This isn't part of original code. I tried adding this here to see if it would solve the problem

        base.Initialize();

        player = new SpaceShip(spaceShip, world);
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        player.Update(gameTime);
    }
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        //Fix transparency of ship
        GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.AlphaBlend;
        GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.None;
        GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise;
        GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearClamp;
        GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
        GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;

        //Draw ship
        player.Draw(spriteBatch, view, proj);

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Spaceship class:

```
class Spaceship
{
    Model ship;
    Vector3 pos;
    Matrix world, translation, yRotation;
    float yYaw;             //value to rotate by
    float totalYRot;        //total rotation

    public SpaceShip(Model model, Matrix transformation)
    {
        ship = model;
        world = transformation;
        pos = Vector3.Zero;
        translation = Matrix.CreateTranslation(pos);
        yYaw = MathHelper.ToRadians(2);
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        //KEYBOARD INPUTS
        //L/R
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        {
            totalYRot += yYaw;
            yRotation = Matrix.CreateRotationY(totalYRot);
        }
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        {
            totalYRot -= yYaw;
            yRotation = Matrix.CreateRotationY(totalYRot);
        }

        //Update world transformation
        world = yRotation * translation;
    }

    public Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Matrix view, Matrix proj)
    {
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in ship.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                //Effect Settings Goes here
                effect.LightingEnabled = false;
                effect.World = world;
                effect.Projection = proj;
                effect.View = view;
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem 2: Transparency issue:**
As can be seen in the Draw() method in Game1.cs, I have implemented some code that I found here on stackoverflow to fix my transparency issue. However I don't understand why this is necessary. I'm in college and most of the students in my year haven't got this issue. I must have gone wrong somewhere.

Help much appreciated. Couldn't find solutions to them here so I decided to write up the question. Hopefully it is useful for others in the future.

Comment: i quess problem is in `world = yRotation * translation;` so if `yRotation` is 0 (inited) when `world` is also 0.

Comment: @DavorMlinaric: I'm embarrassed. Thank you

Comment: you should not be, this is common mistake when all looks correct but it's just not working. if you can't find bug in 10 mins, leave, do something else for half hour then came back and you will found bug. this works for me + it's good for eyes. :)